Trying to install package: ERROR filename.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform
I am trying to install a package for Python, I think I have the right .whl but I'm not good at this.
I'm trying to install pycryptodome-3.21.0-pp310-pypy310_pp73-win_amd64.whl which is saved on my local drive.
I'm using pip 21.2.3 and Python 3.10.0 on my x64 laptop which is running Windows 11.
When I run:
py -m pip install C:\Users\AKA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\pycryptodome-3.21.0-pp310-pypy310_pp73-win_amd64.whl
I get the following error:

ERROR: pycryptodome-3.21.0-pp310-pypy310_pp73-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

I'm not technically-minded at all, this is an attempt to decrypt my Huawei backup files.

pypy310_pp73 is a wheel for PyPy 7.3 compatible with Python 3.10. If you want a wheel for plain CPython 3.10 you would need a different wheel pycryptodome-3.21.0-cp310-abi3-win_amd64.whl but there is no such wheel at https://pypi.org/project/pycryptodome/3.21.0/#files so you have to compile from sources.
Upd. This issue says "PyCryptodome does use so called ABI3 wheels … compatible with all Python versions since Python 3.5…" So try pip install pycryptodome or download and install wheel pycryptodome-3.21.0-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl.

Cheers, pip install pycryptodome fixed my issue. Thank you so much.
